How to set all the buttons who are in an unclickable state back to clickable?
I am practicing with programming a 2-player game where the 2 players take turns on a single screen, for that the buttons clicked by one player during their turn should not be available to the other.
enter image description here
All the red buttons should be disabled for the next turn, but the turn after I want it to turn back to clickable. Is there a way of doing this without accessing all the buttons?
I have tried out having a loop for accessing all of the buttons which have a tag to turn them back to clickable. Just trying to see if there are any other methods.

first of all you should share piece of code so that people can help you.

You could try keeping a reference to the particular buttons that have been clicked in a list and then go through just that list and clear it when no longer relevant.
